# Documentation from link https://api.wavesplatform.com/v0/docs/

Tags: wavesplatform

Please tell me the repository of the documentation Swagger program located on the link https://api.wavesplatform.com/v0/docs and how to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the links for Waves node REST API:
https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-api-and-sdk/waves-node-rest-api.html

Comment: No, the link for Waves data-service docs here https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/waves-api-and-sdk/waves-data-service-api.html. But i need a this package docs form data-service https://api.wavesplatform.com/v0/docs. I need a source code of package docs for install on our vps.

Comment: Did you check the data service repository ?
https://github.com/wavesplatform/data-service/tree/develop/docs

Comment: Yes, after I posted a question on this server, they added documentation to the data-service. But this version is in development. When they release the release can be used.